# PyQt5 QLCDNumber Display

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5, qlcdnumber

I´m new to PyQt5 have been playing with it for about two weeks now and I have encountered an issue with the QLCDNumber display method. I want to be able to display more than 5 digits which I currently can´t with the code I have. After I input the 6th digit the numbers stop showing.
I have researched for about a week on google and youtube but was not able to find a solution.
Code:

```
self.lcd = QLCDNumber(self)
self.lcd.setGeometry(3, 120, 150, 30)
self.lcd.display(91029)
```

This above code works but the below does not display the numbers:

```
self.lcd = QLCDNumber(self)
self.lcd.setGeometry(3, 120, 150, 30)
self.lcd.display(910297)
```

Comment: According to the [official documentation of QLCDNumber](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlcdnumber.html#QLCDNumber-1) you can use `lcd=QLCDNumber(num, parent)` to display `num` digits.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [the docs](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlcdnumber.html#digitCount-prop) points out:

> [**digitCount : int**](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlcdnumber.html#digitCount-prop)
>
> This property holds the current number of digits
> displayed
>
> Corresponds to the current number of digits. If
> QLCDNumber::smallDecimalPoint is false, the decimal point occupies one
> digit position.
>
> **By default, this property contains a value of 5.**
>
> This property was introduced in Qt 4.6.
>
> Access functions:
>
> [`int digitCount()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlcdnumber.html#digitCount) 
> [`const void  setDigitCount(int numDigits)`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlcdnumber.html#setDigitCount)

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

As indicated by default, only up to 5 digits are shown, so if you want to show more or less digits you must use the X method or point it in the constructor:

```py
self.lcd = QLCDNumber(6, self)
self.lcd.setGeometry(3, 120, 150, 30)
self.lcd.display(910297)
```

or

```py
self.lcd = QLCDNumber(self)
self.lcd.setGeometry(3, 120, 150, 30)
self.lcd.setDigitCount(6)
self.lcd.display(910297)
```

Comment: The above answer allowed me to display more digits but I ran into this.
    self.lcd.display(9102970012)
OverflowError: argument 1 overflowed: value must be in the range -2147483648 to 2147483647
Is there a way to display larger numbers with a workaround or is it the max?

Comment: @CarlosDias QLCDisplay only supports C++ int that have that limited range(-2147483648 to 2147483647), if you have a new question on how to display values outside that range like 9102970012 then you must create a new post and maybe someone proposes a workaround.